# Openlayers + OSM tiles on iPad / iPhone

Tags: android, ios, openlayers, openstreetmap

I use OpenStreetMap on a responsive Website and have some display issues.

The map is displayed very well on my Samsung S4 with Android.
The Map is **not** displayed on my iPad2 with OS5 or Sony Z with Android

I use

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);
```

I thought the error is here

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(3, 3) // Center of the map
                        .transform(
                            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                        ), 15 // Zoom level
                    );
```

but the use of transform() without parameters was not successful.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Which Android versions are you using? What do you see when the map is not displayed correctly? Could you post the relevant map display code here or to JSFiddle?

Comment: You use Openlayers3 already?

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dhbtpxv/1/), hope it helps.